# Android 4.4 BLE - can only see one device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am running a simple test to connect to a custom bluetooth device.  I'm using an older Android phone running API 19 (OS level 4.4.2).  When I downloaded a separate BLE scanner app, it's able to find my device and show it in the list when scanning.  However, my own custom code in my app is not finding the device.  The code appears to be working, but in the LeScanCallback's "onLeScan()" method callback, it's only printing one device (a different one than the one I'm needing to find and eventually connect to).

Here is the code I'm using for kicking things off in the Fragment at hand:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ble_fragment, container, false);

    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    initScanCallback();
    startScanWithServices(new ArrayList<String>());

    return view;
}
```

Here is the initScanCallback() method and its associated method for initting the Support one (which is what my code is using):

```
private void initScanCallback(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        initCallbackLollipop(); // not used in this particular case
    } else {
        initScanCallbackSupport();
    }
}

private void initScanCallbackSupport(){
    if(callback != null) return;
    this.callback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
            String address = device.toString();
            String name = device.getName();

            Log.d(TAG, "onLeScan, address: " + address + " | name: " + name + " | rssi: " + rssi);
        }
    };
```

Here is where the scan is started:

```
public void startScanWithServices(List<String> uuidFilters){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        scanLollipop(uuidFilters); // not used in this particular case
    } else {
        scanSupport(uuidFilters);
    }
}

private void scanSupport(List<String> uuidFilters){
    if (callback == null) {
        initScanCallbackSupport();
    }

    boolean success = bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(callback);
}
```

Pretty straight-forward overall.  However, when this code is kicked off, the logs start flooding in immediately with the following:

```
02-03 13:54:13.476 11603-11618/myapp.myapp D/TAG: onLeScan, address: BC:14:85:D3:7D:3D | name: [TV] UN60J6300 | rssi: -102
02-03 13:54:13.946 11603-11817/myapp.myapp D/TAG: onLeScan, address: BC:14:85:D3:7D:3D | name: [TV] UN60J6300 | rssi: -92
02-03 13:54:14.576 11603-11619/myapp.myapp D/TAG: onLeScan, address: BC:14:85:D3:7D:3D | name: [TV] UN60J6300 | rssi: -93
```

I'm not sure what the "TV" device is, most likely my iMac..but it's the only one the logs show as being found.  But again, when I run the BLE scans using other apps downloaded from the Store, the list is populated with multiple devices (including the one I'm needing to find).  So I know it's not my phone itself, nor the bluetooth device, since it's easily found using other apps.

Is there something that could be in place in my code that is preventing multiple devices from being "found" via this callback?

Thank you in advance for any assistance on this!

Comment: How long is your scan running for?

Comment: I let the scan go for many minutes.  It constantly prints the log for that one device over and over, no other devices.  When I run a scan using another app that I downloaded, all my devices show in the list.. So I assume there is something wrong with my code.

Comment: @svguerin3 Have you tried scanning for say more time?Also try having an arraylist and add founded device in that and see after scanning how many devices are there in the list(make sure you dont add duplicate devices)
Sometimes logs are not complete. Comment with tagging me to send me notification.